# Weight Painting Degrade Effect?

Tags: weight-painting

[image]

I want to know if there is a tool to make a degrade effect , i say the start and finish and weight to weight or something like that ..

Answer (score 3):

There is a *gradient tool*, if that's what your looking for.

Activate it with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> or by pressing *Weight Gradient* in the *3D view > Tool shelf > Weight Tools*:

[image]

Comment: Didnt work :/ want to try yourself ? pls :D

Comment: It works for me.. (see attached screenshot) After you press *Weight Gradient*, you have to press LMB and drag in the 3D view to define the gradient.